# incompatible table partitioning specification when using bigquery CLI for an array table

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following SQL:

```
#standardSql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE batch_report
(
  date DATE,
  memberId STRING OPTIONS(description="xxxx member ID"),
  variables ARRAY<STRUCT<
      id STRING,
      datatype STRING,
      effectiveDate TIMESTAMP,
      values ARRAY<STRUCT<
          id STRING,
          value STRING
        >
      >,
    isSensitive BOOLEAN,
    name STRING
    >
  >
)
PARTITION BY date
OPTIONS (
  partition_expiration_days=62, -- two months
  description="Stores the raw response from the xxxx batch endpoint"
)
```

when running this via the CLI using `bq query --dataset=dev < create_batch_report.sql` it will give me the following error message:

```
Incompatible table partitioning specification. Expected partitioning specification none, but input partitioning specification is
interval(type:day,field:date)
```

However, when running it in the BigQuery console and supplying the dataset name in the `CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE` statement, it will execute correctly. Is this a bug, if so how do I get around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When running via the CLI, I modified the first line to include the dataset rather than passing it in using the `dataset` flag. This caused it to execute correctly. I've modified the SQL to be:

```
#standardSql
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE {ENVIRONMENT}.batch_report
(
  date DATE,
  memberId STRING OPTIONS(description="xxxx member ID"),
  variables ARRAY<STRUCT<
      id STRING,
      datatype STRING,
      effectiveDate TIMESTAMP,
      values ARRAY<STRUCT<
          id STRING,
          value STRING
        >
      >,
    isSensitive BOOLEAN,
    name STRING
    >
  >
)
PARTITION BY date
OPTIONS (
  partition_expiration_days=62, -- two months
  description="Stores the raw response from the xxxx batch endpoint"
)
```

and execute it via CLI with:

```
sed s/"{ENVIRONMENT}"/${ENVIRONMENT}/g create_batch_report.sql | \
    bq query
```